# Is there a good approach or metric for determining when the one page backbonejs app needs to be refactored

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, express

I have build a basic backbonejs application and it is one page now handling login, list view and detail views.

I now need to add more business objects to be viewed listed and edited, and I was wondering if there is a best practice on when to move beyond the one page?

BTW it is backbonejs on the front, nodejs and express is on the back

Answer (score 0):

Not really.

You can build the entire thing as a single page app using a router to handle the dispatching between all the various views.

You might want to make "namespace" pages, so like `/auth/` is a file that loads just the auth parts of your site, `/posts/` might be all the blog posts, etc.

This way you're not loading a ton of javascript into the browser in case someone doesn't never need to use a certain function.